# Make Windows 7/8/10 render to a different area than the screen

Tags: windows, winapi

Suppose you have a **1280 x 720** screen on a laptop that's running Windows. You can barely fit one window on the screen.

Would it be possible to write a program that asks Windows to render itself (we're talking the toolbar, wallpaper, *everything*) to, say, a **3840 x 2160** buffer in RAM (in other words a virtual 4k screen in RAM with lots of screen real estate),  then reads this buffer, somehow makes all or part of it fit into a 1280 x 720 buffer, and displays it on the 1280 x 720 laptop screen?

I'm asking because I have an idea for an application that would use this technique, and I don't know the Windows API or graphical system well enough to know if this technique is possible. I'm mostly concerned with Windows 10, but support for earlier versions would be good too.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/692012/how-can-i-make-the-windows-8-desktop-scrollable

Comment: You are certainly free to draw to an off-screen bitmap in any resolution that your video card and system memory allow. You can selectively render that content to your own window, but you can't replace the native desktop being drawn with your own content without that window.

Comment: The [Desktop Duplication API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3ddxgi/desktop-dup-api) *may* be capable of providing the building blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Some graphic cards/ drivers can render the screen in the resolution you want and scale it to the Display resolution, so the image is rendered in 4k and downscaled to 720p resolution and icons and text become really small. This techinique is called virtual resolution. But it affects all your current screen its not specified for your application.

Some game egines can do that too, but i think there is not a simple way to do this using winApi cause the winApi is made to work together with your OS and respect its sizes and display, you cant simple force a diferent resolution for this window.